# ST_DWithin exponentially slow. Cannot find what I am doing wrong

Tags: postgis, distance, performance, st-dwithin

- *PostGIS version: 3.1*
- *PostgreSQL version: 12.3*
- *The machine I am working with has: 126G RAM, 48 CPU cores*

**Info:**

I am getting started with PostGIS.

My goal is to get all the matching data between two points.

lv.geopoint and sub.geopoint both are GEOGRAPHY Points (SRID: 4326) and have GIST indexes on them.

My sub SELECT returns about 3k lines, my ‘valeurs_foncieres’ table however has 14 000 000 lines.

I do have BTREE indexes on valeurs_foncieres.id, caracteristiques_2018.id, caracteristiques_2018.num_acc, usagers_2018.id, usagers_2018.num_acc, vehicules_2018.id, vehicules_2018.num_acc.

**The problem:**

The query gets exponentially slow as I increase the distance of ST_DWithin.

- Precision 100: 2sec
- Precision 1 000: 10sec
- Precision 10 000: 6min

**Here is the query:**

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT(sub.num_acc),
    sub.geopoint,
    sub.id
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        DISTINCT(u.num_acc) AS unumacc, c.*
    FROM
        usagers_2018 u
    INNER JOIN vehicules_2018 v ON
        u.num_acc = v.num_acc
    INNER JOIN caracteristiques_2018 c ON
        u.num_acc = c.num_acc
    WHERE
        u.grav = '2'
    ORDER BY
        c.id
) AS sub
INNER JOIN valeurs_foncieres vf ON
    ST_DWithin(vf.geopoint,
    sub.geog,
    1000,
    FALSE);
```

**Here is the EXPLAIN:**

```
HashAggregate  (cost=265577998.10..265578004.81 rows=671 width=49)
  Group Key: c.num_acc, c.geopoint, c.id
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=9948.38..264845621.97 rows=97650150 width=49)
        ->  Unique  (cost=9947.84..10316.67 rows=6706 width=170)
              ->  Sort  (cost=9947.84..9964.60 rows=6706 width=170)
                    Sort Key: c.id, u.num_acc, c.an, c.mois, c.jour, c.hrmn, c.lum, c.agg, c."int", c.atm, c.col, c.com, c.adr, c.gps, c.lat, c.long, c.dep, c.lat_gps, c.long_gps, c.geopoint, c.geog
                    ->  Gather  (cost=3200.48..9521.63 rows=6706 width=170)
                          Workers Planned: 1
                          ->  Nested Loop  (cost=2200.48..7851.03 rows=3945 width=170)
                                Join Filter: ((u.num_acc)::text = (v.num_acc)::text)
                                ->  Parallel Hash Join  (cost=2200.06..6686.70 rows=2075 width=170)
                                      Hash Cond: ((c.num_acc)::text = (u.num_acc)::text)
                                      ->  Parallel Seq Scan on caracteristiques_2018 c  (cost=0.00..2859.90 rows=33990 width=157)
                                      ->  Parallel Hash  (cost=2174.12..2174.12 rows=2075 width=13)
                                            ->  Parallel Seq Scan on usagers_2018 u  (cost=0.00..2174.12 rows=2075 width=13)
                                                  Filter: ((grav)::text = '2'::text)
                                ->  Index Only Scan using vehicules_2018_num_acc_idx on vehicules_2018 v  (cost=0.42..0.54 rows=2 width=13)
                                      Index Cond: (num_acc = (c.num_acc)::text)
        ->  Index Scan using valeurs_foncieres_geopoint_idx on valeurs_foncieres vf  (cost=0.54..39477.72 rows=1456 width=32)
              Index Cond: (geopoint && _st_expand(c.geog, '1000'::double precision))
              Filter: st_dwithin(geopoint, c.geog, '1000'::double precision, false)
JIT:
  Functions: 30
  Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true
```

**Questions:**

Is this normal? How can I decrease the execution time?

Comment: What is the number of points in each case? I suspect it's proportional to the time.

Comment: I have a point by row, so about 3 000 for the sub SELECT and 7 000 000 valid points on the 14 000 000 'valeurs_foncieres' table (Not valid == Point(0, 0)). I tried cleaning the table, but the index seems to work quite well because the time difference is hardly noticeable.

Comment: Oh sorry you meant as a result. Position 100: 560, Position 1 000: 2 151, Position 1 000: 2 872.

Comment: Even without DISTINCT?

Comment: Without both distinct: Position 100: 25 002 (3s), Position 1 000: 1 860 126 (10.5s), Position 10 000: 12 097 6121 (7min).

Comment: So the query has to generate 12 million rows before they are filtered out with DISTINCT.

Comment: It seems so, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

14 000 000 lines is not small. Also, If the geog that you have are uniformly distributed, the number of points concerned is around x100 when you multiply your radius x10 (the area of the circle depends of r²), so it's normal that your time augmentation seems squared. Here it seems to be more than that, but the more data you manipulate the more operations you will potentially needs because of all the cache gestion and disk call (not true for small data or big cache).

Here the explain seems ok, it uses the index so it's not the problem. You should juste be sure to VACUUM ANALYSE your tables but it shouldn't change much.

The main thing you can do if you didn't is tweak your postgresql. By default, the parameters are really conservative, if you have a big server you need to modify the parameters to use it properly. These parameters can be handle in this file on linux: /etc/postgresql/12/main/postgresql.conf then you need to restart postgres (you can easily find doc on internet if you have questions on that). Typically, what I modify are the following (adapted for around 120Go and 48 CPU of ram) :

- shared_buffers = 30GB
- effective_cache_size = 80GB
- work_mem = 256MB
- maintenance_work_mem = 5GB
- autovacuum_work_mem = 5GB
- effective_io_concurrency = 200 (for SSD, or 2 for disk)
- max_worker_processes = 48
- max_parallel_workers = 48
- max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 12
- wal_buffers = 16MB
- min_wal_size = 1GB
- max_wal_size = 2GB

Those are probably not perfect, and defined partly because of documentation that I found and partly from try and fail on big request. But if you didn't configure your postgresql at all (you said that you started) it should make a big difference in performance for big request (yours is not that big, but it should have an impact). The geometry data is usually big, so it should need more space than typical use of postgresql. Also, if you can, be sure to put your data on SSD, it can have a big impact too.

#### EDIT

I just reread your request, and I don't really understand why you need all the points whithin X meters if after you only keep one line by numacc. Either you didn't put the whole query, or you really only need one point. So I just rewrite it in case what you really wanted was to get the closest point. I used MATERIALIZED CTE, which create temporary table for each step, sometimes it can really improve the performance, so in case you wanted to get all the points and not just the closest neighboor, you can try to run it as is with removing the ORDER BY and the LIMIT in the INNER JOIN LATERAL at the end. And of course here I limit the search with ST_DWithin but if you want a true nearest neighboor you can remove this WHERE :

```sql
WITH usg AS MATERIALIZED
(
    SELECT
            DISTINCT(u.num_acc) AS unumacc
            , c.*
        FROM
            usagers_2018 u
        WHERE
            u.grav = '2'
        INNER JOIN caracteristiques_2018 c ON
            u.num_acc = c.num_acc
        ORDER BY
            c.id
), sub AS MATERIALIZED
(
    SELECT
            DISTINCT(usg.unumacc)
            , usg.*
            , v.*
        FROM
            usg
        INNER JOIN vehicules_2018 v ON
            usg.num_acc = v.num_acc
)
SELECT
        sub.*
        , vf.*
    FROM sub
    INNER JOIN LATERAL 
        (
            SELECT
                    vf.*
                FROM
                    valeurs_foncieres vf
                WHERE
                    ST_DWithin(
                        vf.geopoint
                        ,sub.geog
                        , 1000
                        ,FALSE
                    )
                ORDER BY vf.geopoint <-> sub.geog
                LIMIT 1
        )   
    ON TRUE;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this makes more sense now. I have tried a few things listed in [PostGIS documentation](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.4/performance_tips.html#small_tables_large_objects). I also have tried VACUUM ANALYSE without much success. I will try modifying Postgres's parameters.

Comment: I did get a considerable improvement with changing Postgre's parameters with a lot of distance. Position 10 000 now takes about 4mins. Thank you again.

Comment: Hi, I need to thank you a third time. As you guessed I did not include every columns in the SELECT (I got about 7 others).
I did need the closest point (Didn't realise until now).
Your query with 10km takes < 300ms which is insane.
I had to google a lot of things from your query and I do not get 100% how it's that much faster so I'll go with magic until I understand it all.
Have a great day !

Comment: Nice :) If it's that fast you can try to remove the MATERIALIZED to see if it's faster, sometimes it can slow down a little (and sometimes it speed up, it's complicated to anticipate this actually, you just need to try). INNER JOIN LATERAL is way faster because for each line of the sub CTE, it will find only the closest point (limit 1) using the index and then stop, whereas a INNER JOIN will first create a line for all the point in 10km radius before selecting the first one with your DISTINCT

Comment: hey @robinloche, thanks a lot for sharing your knowledge there. We owe you there. If you find yourself in Paris, come by our office, beers/tea/coffee are on us. (check your LinkedIN).