# QGIS: Split polygon coverage into subsets of non-overlapping polygons

Tags: qgis, polygon, graph

I know this is similar to some earlier questions but I need a solution in QGIS.

I need to divide a large polygon coverage into n subset coverages in which polygons do not overlap. I know this is a "graph coloring problem" and I've seen solutions in ArcGIS and PostgreSQL but I'm looking for a way to do this in QGIS and I am not familiar enough with any of these systems to translate the code.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE ! Can you add links to the similar questions on ArcGIS or PostgreSQL you found earlier ?

Comment: Can you add a picture of what you have and what you want

Comment: Here you go: [picture](https://photos.google.com/search/_tra_/photo/AF1QipP7Vq2yUevoafsO0m_oZ0pTfpAxDi6qr2I0Vz_m)

Comment: Some posts: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32217/exploding-overlapping-to-new-non-overlapping-polygons  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/417113/postgis-split-polygons-into-intersecting-and-non-intersecting-and-grouping-on-o